# how to send a structure over websockets

Tags: javascript, c++, json, html, websocket

I want to send a structure

```
struct s {
    unsigned int a;
    unsigned short b;
    unsigned char str[16];

}
```

how to send a structure like above with javascript? and I can't use json.

Comment: You can't use JSON? Why not? Can't you just pack it all in a string? Also, be more specific about what you're trying to accomplish and why you need to pass around a C struct declaration.

Comment: my server written in c++. it doesn't have support for json.

Comment: There are JSON implementations for C++. Anyway, you'll just have to serialize your data in *some* way. JSON is one way to do it, but there are plenty of other options. You just have to convert the data into a string or a byte sequence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to "send the structure" in such a way that you won't have to do any unpacking in your server. The struct definition only makes sense to the C++ server, and even there the way it's mapped into memory isn't guaranteed. You're going to need some sort of serialization (translating program data into a parse-able data stream for storage or transport), and text formats like XML and JSON are a simple and reliable way of doing it. I would go with JSON since it's supported natively by Javascript; all you have to do is add properties to an object and then [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) it. The real work is on the server side. There, you would need to use a library such as [JsonCpp](http://jsoncpp.sourceforge.net/) or [nosjob](http://fossil.wanderinghorse.net/repos/nosjob/index.cgi/index) to read the JSON data. Then you can store each value in your struct manually.